200 fat grams or 200 grams of fat?
As far as I know when there is a long phrase with people, we typically use "of" to show possession like: the house of one of our teachers at school, but 200 fat grams isn't a long phrase, why both these words is correct?
Where we can just use simple noun compounds like this without "of"?
Where do we should use"of"?

'Fat' doesn't describe the grams; '200 grams' is the quantity of fat we are talking about. Nothing to do with 'of' as a possessive.

You mean 22 grams of fat is wrong? But I asked chat gpt and it said it's true and it's used in formal situations

"200 grams of fat" is fine though in Britain it would usually be "200 grammes of fat"

Related.

Answers go in the answer box, not the comment box.

I’m voting to close this question because this is about the correct way to write expressions with SI units, which has a strict set of rules but isn't part of the English language.

@StuartF I highly doubt this has anything at all with do with matters metric: please see my comments on Phil Sweet’s answer about how measure phrases like six pints of bitter can never become six bitter pints. Postnominal X-of-Y measure phrases simply do not allow for prenominal alternates the way postnominal X-of-Y possessives do.

Never ever trust ChatGPT on facts. If you use It to answer a question, you must then check that it hasn't just made the answer up. 'Generative LLMs have been observed to confidently assert claims of fact which do not seem to be justified by their training data, a phenomenon which has been termed "hallucination"' Wikipedia

Are the grams fat? No, they are just regular grams, so it isn't correct.
You write  "grams of fat" because you want to keep "fat" a noun, and 200 grams is just the quantity.

While fat ᴄᴀɴ be an adjective as in fat chance, using it as an attributive modifier need not force an adjectival interpretation here; it might still be an attributive noun. You can see this more clearly with a word like protein that lacks a corresponding same-spelt adjective. Compare How many ounces of protein do you need per day? with  How many daily protein ounces do you need? Clearly both uses of protein in those do so with protein only as a noun, never an adjective here. In the same way, “drinks with low fat” leaves fat as a noun in the equivalent “low fat drinks”.


Using Keizer's classification of pseudopartitives  (Reference
Keizer 2007: 109) in which she distinguishes between five types,
adapting a classification proposed for Dutch in Vos (Reference Vos
1999)
[CUP]

... and including a true partitive of the same form:
                     [(1) True partitive: [a] half of them]

(a) Quantifier-noun constructions: a number of people
(b) Measure-noun constructions: a pint of beer
(c) Container-noun constructions: a box of chocolates
(d) Part-noun constructions: a piece of cake
(e) Collection-noun constructions: a herd of elephants

We can examine the viability of a transformation where a string such as

'a teacher of science' becomes 'a science teacher'
'a bar of gold' becomes 'a gold bar'
'a slave of fashion' becomes 'a fashion slave'

where we have premodification by an attributive noun to replace the of-phrase.
Firstly, note that the last three examples are neither partitive nor pseudopartitive ('a piece of cake' may be; if considered as say a sixth of the Swiss Roll on the table it is pseudopartitive, but not considered in isolation, any more than 'a stick of rhubarb' or 'a bar of soap').
And only the last of the three refers even remotely to possession: 'a teacher of science' uses the 'whose metier/expertise is' sense of 'of', and 'a bar of gold' uses the 'chemically/structurally composed of' sense. 'Servant of the king' would become 'king's servant', using the Saxon genitive. [A] car of John's uses the 'double possessive' construction, different again.
Restricting analysis to the partitive and pseudopartitive examples:

(1) '[A] them half' is obviously unacceptable. Other examples such as 'the population half' and 'the water some' (articles are usually needed with the originals) are equally unacceptable.

(a) Quantifier-noun constructions: 'a people number' cannot be used in place of 'a number of people'.

(b) Measure-noun constructions: 'a beer pint' cannot be used in place of 'a pint of beer'.

(c) Container-noun constructions: 'a chocolate box' is rather different from  'a box of chocolates'.

(d) Part-noun constructions: 'a cake piece' is not inconceivable but would not usually be used in place of 'a piece of cake'. And 'a jigsaw piece', quite idiomatic, is not a really close synonym of 'a piece of a jigsaw'.

(e) Collection-noun constructions: 'an elephant herd' could well be used in place of 'a herd of elephants'. Similarly, 'a lion pride', 'a bee swarm', 'a stair flight', 'a trash heap', 'a wolf pack' (from 'a pack of wolves', of course). But a skunk stench?  A goose gaggle? A ferret business? A lady /beauty bevy?


It is good that exploring the last type of pseudopartitives brings out the unpredictability of whether or not the attributive transformation is available. The same may be true for the other four types, but apart from examples where the meaning changes at least slightly, there seem to be very few instances where the attributive transformation is available. Certainly '200 fat grams' sounds at best comical, probably because of the availability of the identical adjective, and best avoided in a serious conversation  piece of writing. 'A silver mole' should not be used for 'a mole of silver'. 'A beer pint' sounds worse, and 'demand one's flesh pound' insulting to the Bard.

Thank you. I truly believe her question is actually more along the lines of why a pint of bitter cannot become a bitter pint: “If the bitter cup does not pass, drink it and be strong, trusting in happier days ahead.” All this sanctioned SI unit expression prescription-vs-proscription regulatory sanctity is like a school of three red herrings, but unlike a three red herring school or a yuletide one horse open sleigh. :)

A rednose mole would doubtless lead many up the garden path. // It's not time for such frivolity yet. Leave the pumpkin juice for another week couple.
